# Displaying an array in Angular JS Modal window

Tags: angularjs

I'm intending to create a salesforce app using angularjs and ionic framework. I've been trying in vain to visualize an arbitrary array in a modal window and failing. Have asked elsewhere but no luck. My plunkr is: http://plnkr.co/edit/wZVItjUwYPExllECYzM7

As you can see, clicking "display" brings up the window but the array is not displayed.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngGrid'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('DisplayCtrl', function($scope, ModalFactory) {

$scope.array = []; //initialize to null

$scope.run = function() { 

$scope.array = $scope.array.concat( [{ //arbitrary array of UNKNOWN fields
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1
}, {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 8
}, {
  "a": 2,
  "b": 5
}, {
  "a": 3,
  "b": 7
}, {
  "a": 4,
  "b": 0
}, {
  "a": 5,
  "b": 3
}, {
  "a": 6,
  "b": 6
}, {
  "a": 7,
  "b": 4
}, {
  "a": 8,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "a": 9,
  "b": 9
}]);

    //$scope.array = array;
    ModalFactory.init($scope).then(function(modal) {
                            modal.show();
                });
}

});
```

HTML is

```
<div class="modal">
<ion-header-bar>
  <h1 class="title">output array</h1>
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios7-close-empty" ng-click="closeModal()"></button>
</div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div ng-grid="{data: 'array'}" class="grid"></div>
</ion-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "Inspect Element" when the dialog has been displayed in Plunker, the body of the table is in this div:

```
<div class="ngViewport" ... style="width: 638px; height: 16px;">
```

and if you change the 16px to say 350px you see all the table rows.

So the question is how to get [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) to compute the correct height; unfortunately I don't know the answer to that.

**PS**

Possibly this problem https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/189 you are seeing. The basic fix is to add a hard-coded height to your style sheet and that works in your Plunker:

```
.ngViewport {
  height: 200px;
}
```

If the content has a fixed number of rows you can tweak that to match. If the number of rows varies you can pick a size and a scroll bar appears if the content is bigger.

Comment: Thank you, lets wait if we can get some more answers. If not I'll mark yours as accepted.